# Qt: having problems responding on QWebView::linkClicked(QUrl) - slot signal issue

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I am pretty new with Qt.

I want to respond to `linkClicked` in `QWebView`.

I tried connect like this:

```
QObject::connect(ui->webView, SIGNAL(linkClicked(QUrl)),
                 MainWindow,SLOT(linkClicked(QUrl)));
```

But I was getting error: `C:/Documents and Settings/irfan/My Documents/browser1/mainwindow.cpp:9: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token`

When I do this using UI Editing Signals Slots:

I have in header file declaration of slot:

```
void linkClicked(QUrl &url);
```

in source cpp file :

```
void MainWindow::linkClicked(QUrl &url)
{
   QMessageBox b;
   b.setText(url->toString());
   b.exec();
}
```

When I run this it compiles and runs but got a warning :

```
Object::connect: No such slot MainWindow::linkClicked(QUrl) 
  in ui_mainwindow.h:100
```

What is proper way of doing this event handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `QObject::connect` to only `connect` and it works.

So this code works:

`connect(ui->webView,SIGNAL(linkClicked(const QUrl)),this,SLOT(linkClicked(const QUrl)),Qt::DirectConnection);`

But I don't know why?

Comment: And also declaration of slots: changed to be with const...

linkClicked(const QUrl &url)

Answer (score 2):

You state that it now works because you changed `QObject::connect` to `connect`. Now I'm not 100% on this but I believe the reason for this is that by calling `connect`, you are calling the method associated with an object which is part of your application. i.e. it's like doing `this->connect(...)`. That way, it is associated with an existing object - as opposed to calling the static method `QObject::connect` which doesn't know anything about your application.

Sorry if that's not clear, hopefully I got the point across!

Answer (score 2):

Using QObject::connect() and connect() is same in this context. I believe

```
QObject::connect(ui->webView,SIGNAL(linkClicked(QUrl)),
                 MainWindow,SLOT(linkClicked(QUrl)));
```

was called from a function inside MainWindow class. That is why when you tried

```
connect(ui->webView,SIGNAL(linkClicked(const QUrl)),
        this,SLOT(linkClicked(const QUrl)),Qt::DirectConnection);
```

it works. Notice the difference that make it work - the third parameter. You used *this* in the second snippet, where as you used *MainWindow* in the first snippet.

Read [this](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/signalsandslots.html) to know how signals and slots mechanism works and how to properly implement it.